# Sketch Filter - windows phone 8.1 silverlight using C#

Tags: c#, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

I have an image in  WriteableBitmap format now I want to apply a sketch filter on it and show it in an image control without saving. 
how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Lumia Imaging SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn859593.aspx) has a [SketchFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lumia.imaging.artistic.sketchfilter.aspx) you can use.

Here's a quick function which will apply a SketchFilter to wbIn and return the filtered image in wbOut

```
using Lumia.Imaging;
using Lumia.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime;
using Lumia.Imaging.Artistic;
```

...

```
async Task FilterWriteableBitmap(WriteableBitmap wbIn, WriteableBitmap wbOut)
{
    using (var imageSource = new BitmapImageSource(wbIn.AsBitmap()))
    using (var filterEffect = new FilterEffect(imageSource))
    using (var renderer = new WriteableBitmapRenderer(filterEffect,wbOut)) 
    {
        var filter = new SketchFilter(SketchMode.Color);

        filterEffect.Filters = new IFilter[] { filter };

        await renderer.RenderAsync();
    }
}

...

await FilterWriteableBitmap(originalWB,filteredWB)
img.Source = filteredWB;
```